# How can I replace this code with map () function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
thlst = [threading.Thread(target=i.report) for i in users] ;
for th in thlst :
    th.start();
```

I think the 2 last lines can be replaced by map() function but I have no idea how it can be.

Thanks for any helps.

Comment: Though you can, you shouldn't. Map is a functional construct that should be used when you're computing a list based an a argument that's also a list. Here you're ignoring the return value of start and relying on side-effects, so that doesn't apply.

Comment: You don't need those semicolons in Python.

Comment: You will still need to consume the map object to actually apply the method so it is really down to 2 lines become 1 plus generating values to be discarded. If you need `thlst` then I would just stick with the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lambda expression, doesn't save you much typing though, or help in any way really.

```
   map(lambda x: x.start(),thlst)
```

Comment: I would consider this poor form - the whole point of ``map()`` is to produce a new sequence from an existing one, but in this case the new sequence is immediately discarded (and consists entirely of ``None``s, anyway).

Comment: Also, that's not how `map` works. Python's `map` is a function, not a list method.

Comment: 1. `map` isn't a method on `list`s, it's a built-in function. 2. This doesn't actually require a `lambda`, since the objects are of known type, you can just pass the unbound method as the transform function and avoid an extra layer of method calls: `map(threading.Thread.start, thlst)` 3. As noted in comments on the question, this is a misuse of `map` that really shouldn't be encouraged; `map` is for functional programming, which is input and output based, and side-effect free. Using it for side-effects is deceptive (and creates a temporary `list` of junk results for no reason).

Comment: Whoops, sorry too much JS, rewrote it in python

Answer (score 1):

While it is pointless, and there is nothing wrong with what you have...

You don't really even need `map()`

Make a list-comprehension, but don't assign it. Basically the same thing `map()` would do anyway

```
[th.start() for th in thlst]
```

If you really don't need `thlst`, then just start them right-away

```
[threading.Thread(target=i.report).start() for i in users]
```

Similarly,

```
map(lambda u: threading.Thread(target=u.report).start(), users)
```

Comment: Why building a list if it won't be used?
for i in users:
    <start the thread>

Comment: @JorgePlaza The question seemed to be asking for alternatives to what was in the question, no?

Comment: @cricket_007 I get your point, I just think it's not a good alternative to suggest building the list